# Encrypted partitions with Ubuntu 22.04, boots to initramfs prompt

Tags: ubuntu, luks, initramfs, disk-encryption

I have painstakingly followed the Ubuntu help doc for setting up encrypted partitions [located here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019).

After the final step (remove USB and reboot), the system boots normally, asking for password.

```
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Enter passphrase for hd0.gpt1 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):
```

I enter that, then system goes continues loading until finally showing:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I selected the defaults for installing (did not select a minimal type installation).

Edit, I attempted rebooting this time after entering hard drive password, system boots to:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word. TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

I've worked on this for two days (this is the 3rd time I've slowly gone through the help doc above, each with the same result).